# Disable iTunes 11 arrows

Tags: itunes

Is there any way to remove these arrows from the songs list?
I know they only appear on hover but are still annoying. I always hit them accidentaly when trying to play a song.

[image: A wild iTunes arrow appears]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer possible. There used to be a way to disable them (iTunes 10 and earlier), but the ability was removed in iTunes version 11.